# Create array from ActiveRecords Association CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Group model which `has_many` Topics. The Topics model `has_many` Posts.
I want to create an array of all Topics for a Group sorted by the Post attribute `:published_on`.

On my Group show page I have `@group.topics.collect {|x| x.posts }` which returns an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` array with each element containing an array of post objects.

```
[
[[topic1 post],[topic1 post],[topic1 post]],
[[topic2 post],[topic2 post],[topic2 post]],
[[topic3 post],[topic3 post],[topic3 post]],
]
```

How do I create a single array of posts sorted by :published_on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that

```
group.topics.includes(:posts).order("posts.published_on").map(&:posts).flatten
```

would be enough.

Comment: Agree with this answer. I'd use `.pluck(:posts)` instead of `.map`

Answer (score 2):

You can also resolve this with the correct relations.

On your `Group` model you could do something like:

```
# you already have this relation
has_many :topics
# you add this
has_many :posts, through: :topics
```

That [through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) works using `topics` like a bridge for `posts`, and returning all `posts` that your `group` have.

And than, your query would look something like
`group.posts.order(:published_on)`